# Skipping precompilation since __precompile__(false)

Tags: julia

I am developing little webapp with Genie 4 in Julia 1.7.3 on Linux mint 21. I have made some modules. While loading the app I got the following,

```
[ Info: 2022-09-13 21:28:08 Precompiling CreateApproveTeamPosts [top-level]
┌ Warning: Module FollowersController with build ID 963745445272 is missing from the cache.
│ This may mean FollowersController [top-level] does not support precompilation but is imported by a module that does.
└ @ Base loading.jl:1107
[ Info: 2022-09-13 21:28:27 Skipping precompilation since __precompile__(false). Importing CreateApproveTeamPosts [top-level].
```

Questions:

1. Can anyone please explain whats happening?
2. In entire project, I don't have `__precompile__(false)`. From where it's coming?

Comment: This might happen when there is a problem with a third-party file, library or app needed to precompile part of the the Julia package (for example if there is a Python library that is missing). In such cases the __precompile___ flag gets set to false because the compile will fail. Sometimes checking your Linux environment and paths for needed libraries may help.